# Streaming video from server to mobile using base64

Tags: php, android, video, base64

We are building an application that deals with images and videos and the privacy requirement is high , where users are not allowed to gain access to the images and videos at all time (privacy option) ,

therefore we went with the option of having a php api that clients request the file and the api returns a base64 encoded response that the client decode and display ,that is for image side ,as for video we are having a trouble finding the right logic .

does `VideoView`  in android helps me achieve this ?

does the api needs to send the video in chunks instead of one large base64 ?

is base64 even right for this requirement ,noting that user should not have direct access to the file at all times .

php api function :

```
function viewFile($data) {

$file = file_get_contents($data['file_path']);
$mime = mime_content_type($data['file_path']);

return ['status' => 200, 'file' => ['mime' => $mime, 'base64' => base64_encode($file)]];
}
```

Comment: Bad idea to use base64 while streaming. That to begin with.

Comment: @greenapps is there an example of streaming php api with authorization without base64 ? the only reason i'm using base64 is it's controllable on both server and client sides ,if there is any other option i'm more than happy to use

Comment: Just do not base64 encode it. That's all. And why would authorisation have to do something with what and how you send the bytes?

Comment: @greenapps say user A shared a file to user B , B  gave the url of the file to user C , if C used the url he should not  be able to download or stream the file (vidoe) .

Answer (score 2):

Security with base64? That does not exist. I made a text (in Portuguese) that might help you. [Read](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264482/como-bloquear-downloads-do-meu-servidor/264488#264488).

I do not recommend using a very large base64. The server will have a lot of load, the download will be slow, etc.

The ideal is to divide it into smaller pieces. For this you can use [bento4](https://www.bento4.com/documentation/mp4dash/) e o [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html).

For images, I recommend using Cipher. [More information for Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) and [More information for PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mcrypt.ciphers.php)

I made this code to encrypt images. It is already quite old, but I think I can help you enteder this issue.

https://github.com/valdeirpsr/estudo-openssl/blob/master/library/OpensslEncrypt/OpensslEncrypt.php

Comment: the security level is not on encrypting the image, but gaining access to it ,so if the image url get exported ,no one can view the image unless they request the api with the right authorization , and i'll check the links thank you

Comment: @Ahmed na. Please reread your post as you clearly stated that security comes by using base64. You are not even talking about getting access.

Comment: @greenapps maybe I've used the wrong term , I updated to privacy requirement